# How to use popper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I have a Laravel project, and I don't want to use bootstrap in it. can I import and use the popper.js plugin without using bootstrap?

When I try to do this, It just shows me the popover title.

Comment: https://codepen.io/javapda/pen/LXRjMd

Comment: You mean using popup instead?

Comment: yes, is there any other requirement

Answer (score -1):

It might be two possibilities.
    1) Css wasn't affected.
    2) Some javascript error.
   I am sending a documentation link. Still, you are facing an error. Please send me code snippet.

[Popper document link](https://www.javascripting.com/view/popper-js)